# Add one character before every special character in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I want to add one character for every special character in a string by regular expression i tried below expression but it is adding after the special character.

I expect the output to add one character for every special character in a string.

```
var string1="aaa!dd,"
var expressionResult = text.replace(/([\/,!?_])/g, '/');
```

the output should be aaa/!dd/,

Comment: Use `text.replace(/[\/,!?_]/g, '/$&')`. BTW, your regex does not match *every* special character. What chars are "special" to you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$1` in the replacement string to include the capture group's content in the replacement:

```js
var string1="aaa!dd,"
var expressionResult = string1.replace(/([\/,!?_])/g, '/$1');
console.log(expressionResult);
```

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

You don't need a capture group, though, you can use `$&` to refer to the text matched by the main expression:

```js
var string1="aaa!dd,"
var expressionResult = string1.replace(/[\/,!?_]/g, '/$&');
console.log(expressionResult);
```

(If you needed to do something more complex in the replacement, you can pass in a function as the second argument. It gets called with the overall match as its first argument, followed by arguments for each capture group; its return value is used in the resulting string. You don't need that here, but...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use back reference to the group `$&` [**MDN ref**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

```js
var string1="aaa!dd,"
var expressionResult = string1.replace(/[\/,!?_]/g, '/$&');

console.log(expressionResult)
```

By special character if you mean everything else than alphabet and digits than you can change your regex to

```
[^a-z\d]  - Match anything except alphabet and digit
```

```js
var string1="aaa!dd,"
var expressionResult = string1.replace(/[^a-z\d]/g, '/$&');

console.log(expressionResult)
```